# Synchronize write to two collections

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

I need to put some value to maps if it is not there yet. The key->value (if set) should always be in two collections (that is `put` should happen in two maps atomically). I have tried to implement this as follows:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Object> map1 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Object> map2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

public Object putIfAbsent(String key) {
    Object retval = map1.get(key);
    if (retval == null) {
        synchronized (map1) {
            retval = map1.get(key);
            if (retval == null) {
                Object value = new Object(); //or get it somewhere
                synchronized (map2) {
                    map1.put(key, value);
                    map2.put(key, new Object());
                }
                retval = value;
            }
        }
    }
    return retval;
}

public void doSomething(String key) {
    Object obj1 = map1.get(key);
    Object obj2 = map2.get(key);
    //do smth
}
```

Will that work fine in all cases? Thanks

Comment: Are you having any difficulties? Have you tested?

Comment: In general, "have you tested?" is a good question. With concurrency, testing won't help much. Because being correct is more about guaranteeing (through proofs, though often informal ones) that something can't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems:

- Don't use "double-checked locking". A quick Google search will reveal tons of articles which explain the problems with this technique. Just check inside the `synchronized` block.
- You don't need to synchronize on both `map1` and `map2`. Just use one or the other.
- Synchronize within `doSomething`. Make sure you synchronize on the *same* object which is used for synchronization in `putIfAbsent`.

Comment: Maybe better would be to use a separate lock object, maybe even a `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`.  This would separate concerns better.

Comment: How would it "separate concerns" better? All it would do is make the code more verbose. Separate lock objects are useful when you need different semantics from `synchronized` (such as when you want to allow multiple concurrent readers). Otherwise you're just writing more code for no reason.

Comment: If you synchronise on the map, then the map (that is arbitrarily chosen) is both the lock object and a data structure.  IMO, it is better to separate these concerns, particularly as this circumstance would potentially benefit greatly from using a readers/writer lock.

Comment: If this code is performance-sensitive, then definitely, a readers/writer lock would be best, and an explicit `Lock` object would then be called for. Otherwise, he would really be better off just declaring the methods as `synchronized`. I say keep it short and sweet... but if something else works better for you, then more power to you!

Comment: Thanks. Particularly, in this code - do you see what is wrong with DCL? I have introduced that in order to avoid double insertion. AFAIK, all necessary memory barriers will be passed as I use ConcurHM. Regarding synchronization in doSomething: can I avoid that? Otherwise, I just can make both of these methods `synchronized` - but this will be overwhelming. Probably, I'd better change CHM to Collections.synchronizedMap. In this case I can leave everything as is, because locks in `putIfAbsent` will be the same as in `synchronizedMap.get()`. What do you think?

Comment: And regarding your second advice to synchronize only on one map. Taking into account that maps are to be thread safe, the only thing I need is to keep their state consistent to each other (i.e. presence or absence of entries associated with one key in both collections in every moment). Thus insertion should lock both collections.

Comment: @glaz666, in current Java implementations, the DCL you use here may work, but it's not guaranteed to work by the Java Memory Model. Changing to `synchronizedMap` is *not* a replacement for making the methods `synchronized`. To keep your collections consistent, *all* operations which use them must hold a lock for the duration of the operation, and they must all use the *same* lock. Using `synchronizedMap`s doesn't achieve that, because each will synchronize on **its own separate lock**. Also, `map1.get()` will **release** `map1`'s intrinsic lock **before** you get to `map2.get()`.

Comment: @glaz666, your comment about "locking both collections" implies that you may not really understand how "locking" works. I can try to explain, but it will take more than a brief comment here. Do you want to start a private chat?

Answer (score 0):

You should never use synchronized with ConcurrentHashMap (it's pretty much defeating the purpose).  The best way to make atomic additions to CHH is by using the built-in replace method.  For example:

```
do {

    oldValue1 = map1.get(key1);
    oldValue2 = map2.get(key2);
    newValue1 = // some logic to determine a new value for key1/value1
    newValue2 = // some more logic to determine a new value for key2/value2

} while (!map1.replace(key1, oldValue1, newValue1) && !map2.replace(key2, oldValue2, newValue2));
```

I don't know how to specifically adapt this to your example, but this should give you somewhere to start.  Basically what happens is you get the key from the map, do some logic, and if the key is still the same as it was before the logic, it will replace the entry and return true, then the loop will break.  Otherwise it will just repeat the loop until it can do the update atomically.

Comment: I was originally going to suggest something like this but how do you hide the update to map2 until the update to map1 succeeds? You might assume that both updates will succeed eventually but still one will happen first and during that interval you see the inconsistency.

Comment: If you only put and never remove from or clear the maps you could establish a protocol. Always add to map1 last. Always read from map1 first. If map1 has no value while reading, ignore map2.

Comment: You can also verify both maps in the condition check before making a write

Comment: If I understand your proposal right, no. That gives you eventual consistency, which you already had, assuming there are no other writers. The OP asked for atomicity. If I'm misunderstanding, please show in code what you mean by "verify both maps in the condition check"?

Comment: while (!map1.replace(key1, oldValue1, newValue1) && !map2.replace(key2, oldValue2, newValue2))

Comment: The protocol which @JohnWatts suggests here also fails to establish atomicity, because thread 1 could add a value to `map1`, then thread 2 could come along and use the Maps before the value is added to `map2`.

Comment: This will replace the old value of map1 for key1 and the old value of map2 for key2 only if no changes have been made to either map by the time the loop started, thus it guarantees atomicity.  It just doesn't guarantee that something in either map won't change while in the loop, which will just cause the loop to repeat itself

Comment: As the OP's question was regarding 2 collections, I have updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: @AlexD please re-read the protocol. It says that map1 is always modified last. Once a thread sees a value in map1, it can be sure that map2 has already had a value with the same key inserted. Incidentally, your synchronized proposal is probably more appropriate. But if you use that I would just use regular HashMaps.

Comment: @JohnWatts, OK, thanks for pointing this out. But please note that the protocol still fails if a previously existing key is mapped to a new value.

Comment: @JordanDenison, this is an interesting idea, but it's not atomic. Your `replace` call could succeed for `map1`, and then another thread could come along and observe the Maps before you get to the next `replace` call. "Atomicity" means that other threads can never see the data in an intermediate state.

Comment: @JordanDenison Atoms are supposed to be indivisible, in spite of Einstein, Oppenheimer,  et al. That means we shouldn't be able to see the write to map1 without seeing the write to map2 and vice versa. Your code provides certain guarantees and might be what the OP wants but it is not fully atomic.

Comment: @AlexD You are correct. I should have included "replace" in my list of excluded operations. Again, using synchronized, as in your solution, is by far the best general purpose answer. This one could be useful for some very restricted cases, but must be done very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally came to this solution:

```
private Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
private Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();

private final ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public void putIfAbsent(String key, Object o) {
    rwl.readLock().lock();
    try {
        if (map1.get(key) == null) {
            rwl.readLock().unlock();
            rwl.writeLock().lock();
            try {
                if (map1.get(key) == null) {
                    map1.put(key, getValue());
                    map2.put(key, getValue());
                }
            }finally {
                rwl.readLock().lock();
                rwl.writeLock().unlock();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        readLock.unlock();
    }
}

public void readMap(String key) {
   rwl.readLock().lock();
    try {
       Object obj1 = map1.get(key);
       Object obj2 = map2.get(key);
    } finally {
        rwl.readLock().unlock();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to do what you want, I'd use atomic references:

```
class PairHolder {
   public final ConcurrentMap map1;
   public final ConcurrentMap map2;
   public PairHolder(...) // set values here.
}

private AtomicReference<PairHolder> mapHolder = ... // initialize it somehow

do {
  PairHolder holder = mapHolder.get();
  ConcurrentMap map1 = holder.map1.clone()
  ConcurrentMap map2 = holder.map2.clone()
  newMap1.putIfAbsent(...);
  newMap2.putIfAbsent(...);
} while (!mapHolder.compareAndSet(holder, new PairHolder(newMap1,newMap2))
```

this way you alway will be sure, that mapHolder contains the reference to PairHolder, which in turn have two maps updated 100% atomically. At least CAS should guarantee this, however on multi-processor systems it might be false.

Comment: I feel that collections can be modified by another thread, and when mapHolder will be substituted with new one referencing to another collections, you may loose inserted items.

Comment: no way, because maps are cloned BEFORE modification, so neither thread works with shared map instance.